# Build clang format with Debug Symbols

Tags: debugging, ninja, clang-format

I have built clang 3.6 from source and followed the rather straightforward instruction on the page and installed ninja, which I confirmed can build clang-format.

My question is quite simply how to pass some flags so I can get debug symbols because I do not want to do my work (modifying clang-format) using disassembly throughout.

This can be through the standard build (which uses CMake) or ninja.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar issue recently (I wanted to debug clang's code itself). Turned out that you need to explicitly specify `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` when you run CMake to generate Ninja or standard makefiles.

BTW, be careful: with this Debug option `ld` "ate" about 4G of my RAM to link `clang` binary...